# OpenCV - Error in Displaying Webcam Video

Tags: c, opencv, webcam

I'm pretty new to OpenCV and I'm trying to get my bearings by looking at, and running, sample code.

One of the sample programs that I was looking at is a program for displaying webcam video. Here are the important lines (the program doesn't execute farther than this):

```
// Make frame.
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

if(!capture) {
    printf("Webcam not initialized....");
}
// Display video in frame.
```

Unfortunately, the `if` statement always executes. For some reason, `capture` is not initialized.

Even stranger, when I run the program, it even gives me a GUI to select the webcam that I want to use:

[image: Webcam Selection GUI]

However, even after I select the webcam, `capture` is not initialized!

What does this mean? How do I fix this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is anything else running that may be using the camera, eg skype ?

Comment: +1 Martin Beckett. I'm sure that this is camera driver issue (or v4l in linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that OpenCV cannot access the webcam until after you select it. In that case, try looping until the webcam is available:

```
CvCapture *capture = NULL;
do {
    // you could also try passing in CV_CAP_ANY or -1 instead of 0
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
} while (!capture);
```

If this still doesn't work, call `cvErrorStr(cvGetErrStatus())` to get a string explaining the error.

Comment: `capture` was initialized, but then the window that I got was blank.... Thanks for addressing my question, though.

Comment: In that case, as the other commenters suggest, I would recommend checking if you have the latest version of OpenCV and checking your video drivers, possibly using another camera if you are unable to get the current one to work.